# Find relation between $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ in the given figure(involves a circle and triangles).

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, circles

Source: MAT $2011$
[image]

I cannot decide between two of the MCQ options. Both of them seem correct. 
(a) $\cos\alpha = \sin(\beta+\gamma)$ 
(b) $\sin\beta = \sin\alpha  \sin\gamma$

(a) If I join the centre of the circle to the point where the tangent meets the circle, I'll get a right angled triangle. Thus, angle ACB is $90 + \alpha$ degrees. Now $$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 90$$
$$or, \sin(\beta+\gamma) = \cos\alpha$$

(b) WLOG, let radius of circle = $1$. Then $$AC = \frac{1}{\sin\alpha}$$
Applying sine rule in $\triangle ABC$
$$\sin\beta = \frac{\sin\gamma}{\frac{1}{\sin\alpha}}$$

The answer key says the answer is (b). Then what am I doing wrong in (a)?

Comment: There is no reason why $BCT$ is a straight line, where $T$ is the point of tangency.

Comment: @user10354138 oh right, my bad. That was stupid of me.